# Modifying GDAL rasterize tool using Python

Tags: qgis, python, gdal

I would like to take a look and maybe modify the code of the gdal tool rasterize and I don't find the python file of the tool.

Where can I find the gdal python files so that I can open it and make some changes?

Comment: GDAL is written in C++ not python.  You can see the source code for `gdal_rasterize` on GitHub https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/apps/gdal_rasterize_lib.cpp and https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/apps/gdal_rasterize_bin.cpp

Comment: can I also change the code in my QGIS application?

Comment: Of the rasterize tool? No. It's compiled to a binary executable. You would have to clone the source code from the git repository, make your changes and then compile GDAL from the modified source.

Comment: Unless you're talking about the bit of code in the Processing Toolbox that runs the rasterize tool and you just want to change how arguments are collected and passed to `gdal_rasterize`? You can change that.